# Unable to delete app in iTunes Connect with "Developer Rejected" status

Tags: app-store-connect

My app was rejected. There was no Delete App button in iTunes Connect. I uploaded the binary again, rejected it, and there is still no "Delete App" button under "Transfer App."
How do I delete this app altogether?

I don't have enough points to post an image, but you can see a screen shot here:

[image]

The iTunes Connect Developer Guide states:

> You can delete your app when its status is one of the following:
>
> Prepare for Upload
> Waiting for Upload
> Invalid Binary
> Developer Rejected
> Rejected
> Metadata Rejected
> Developer Removed from Sale
> Removed from Sale"

So why can't I delete an app? I even tried with another app. Same problem.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22224171/194544

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an app which is waiting for upload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114051/how-to-delete-an-app-which-is-waiting-for-upload)

Answer (score 41):

I had a similar problem and contacted iTunes Connect support.
They replied with this:

> I believe the reason that you are unable to delete this app is that it does not have one delivered and approved version. Apps must have at least one approved version before they can be deleted; if your app has never had an approved binary delivered, you will be unable to delete it.

Basically, you're unable to delete an app that was rejected and never approved.

Comment: Mine was approved but not released and I also didn't had the delete button?

Comment: Mark Molina, Not sure why you say it is stupid. Just leave it there and there will be a time when you want to publish another new app. So just modify that app data to the new app data.