# How to delete an app which is waiting for upload?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-name

As per apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW37), We can delete an application which is in a state of waiting for upload.
But, how? I searched for the delete button and can't get that.

[image]

How can a team agent delete it from my itunes connect view?
I can't find the delete button in the app details page.

[image]

Comment: How did you managed it? I'm in your exact situation.

Comment: @MatterGoal, I've mentioned that in my answer, do you have any other clarification?

Comment: nope, I just think that it's so weird that we can't see that button.

Comment: Here is answer to the same problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19575239/1041311

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Still, I can't see the delete button and I can't delete the application.

As the old app's binary version is not uploaded and reviewed, I just renamed that application and then used the name by creating a new one.

Apple accepts the name and the app is now in review.

Answer (score 12):

Recently I received an email from Apple:

> Dear DEVELOPER,
>
> You have not yet uploaded a binary for your app, TheGreatApp. Our
>   records show that this app was created in iTunes Connect more than 173
>   days ago.
>
> If you do not upload a binary for your app by 13 March 2014 (Pacific
>   Time), it will be deleted from iTunes Connect. The app name will then
>   be available for another developer to use.

So, wait for half of year and it will be deleted automatically.

Comment: Solution found, but need a long patience. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Since iTunes connect policy has been changed, If your app is not approved yet, you can't delete the app. Even if you upload your binary and then reject it, it will remains there. The only way delete an app from iTunes Connect it has to be approved once.

From Apple:

> Deleting an App
>
> If you’ve created an app in iTunes Connect that you no longer need to
>   manage, you can delete it from iTunes Connect.
>
> Apps can’t be deleted if they are part of a Game Center group or
>   currently displayed on a store. You’ll want to remove the app from
>   sale or from the group if you want to delete it. See “Removing an App
>   from Sale” or “Removing an App from a Group” in Game Center
>   Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect. **Apps that have not been
>   approved yet can’t be deleted;** instead, reject the app. See “Rejecting
>   Your Binary.”

You can see more details at [Transferring And Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

Comment: That was not different before

Comment: @LiGe If you look at the answers (screenshot) above you can see there was a delete button and you were able to delete.

Comment: Sure but not in the state of Waiting For Upload. Had that problem back in March. Maybe that picture is older than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on App in Detail page you will get option Delete application. But FYI your bundle identifier & name of application registered will not delete.

Answer (score 0):

You just login to the itunes connect

Manage Your Apps-> Select Your App

Now you can see the delete option. i added an sample image here
[image]