# iTunesConnect New UI - How to delete Bundle of three apps created in iTunes?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

i created Bundle of three apps on iTunesConnect which is in "Prepare for Submission" status.
Now i want to delete that created app Bundle but did't find option to delete that created bundle.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461735/how-to-delete-an-app-from-itunesconnect

Comment: Did you finally find a solution for this ?