# How to delete a Rejected app from iTunes Connect

Tags: ios

I submitted an app for Review.
It was rejected with the message 
11.1 - Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

Now I want to delete the app from iTunes Connect.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not really. They just hang around there forever. Is there a reason why it should be deleted, or just would be nice?

Comment: in iTunes Connect there is a build Section. Tap on - sign to remove rejected build.

Comment: I want to know if I can remove apps. If so I can add more apps during testing stage. If it cannot be removed I loose the freedom and I have to be extra cautious before I upload an app here. Just don't feel like having unwanted items lying around.

Comment: I don't see a build section Mihir! I just see Versions
Prerelease
Pricing
In-App Purchases
Game Center
Newsstand
More

Comment: you may find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461735/how-to-delete-an-app-from-itunesconnect

Comment: As of October you can delete https://stackoverflow.com/a/52682672/5306470

Answer (score 1):

I face this issue...

- Provide all details of application and mention **Apple ID** in mail
- Send mail to **eurodev@apple.com**
- It will take 2-4 days to remove

Note: The mail should be send from your register mail-id.