# Delete ios app in "Prepare for Submission" state

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

From the research I have understand that an app cannot be deleted while its in "Prepare for Submission" state.

Now my problem is I want to use the same app Name.
I can compromise on app id and bundle identifier as this is my first version but the app name is really important.
So what should I do.

Second think I have heard app can be deleted from itunes connect if its in review state. So does anyone think its a viable solution to submit app and then delete it.

Comment: Why not just change the metadata (description & screenshots) and upload your new version for the existing app record?  I presume you have never released a version of this existing app?

Answer (score 0):

The app can't be deleted from itunes connect. If you wanna use that app name, you can rename the old app name and set that name for new app.

Comment: You can't truly deleted app A in itunes connect. You can only remove it from sale (app will be removed from App store ). And you can't use bundleID, app name of app A for any app.

Comment: You should be able to delete an app after it went through the review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461735/how-to-delete-an-app-from-itunesconnect