# How can I remove Mac catalyst app from iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, mac-catalyst

I am trying to remove Mac Catalyst app from my new update binary from app store connect.

[image]

But, it seems there is no way to do it. In the App, Information tap the remove option and delete all apps (Universal and Mac).

On my Xcode project I have unchecked the Mac Catalyst option but still cannot remove the macOS app from the iOS app. Any help would be great!

[image]

Comment: It looks like you need to remove your Mac app from sales in App Store connect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461735/how-to-delete-an-app-from-itunesconnect-app-store-connect

Comment: @jnpdx As I mentioned the remove application button remove both iOS and macOS app !!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the following information in an apple forum(maybe it helps):

> I had the same problem and I have found the solution.
> In the documentation, you can find this condition:
> **"You can delete a platform if a build has never been uploaded for the platform you wish to delete. Additionally, at least one existing platform version needs to be in an editable app status."**
> So I have created a news editing version for my iOS app and then I could remove the macOS version of my app.
> I hope this will help you correct your problem

[Link to forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651148)

Comment: ""So I have created a news editing version for my iOS app and then I could remove the macOS version of my app" What is an 'editing version'? After doing this how did you remove the macOS version?