# How to delete unfinished apps in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Got a couple of unfinished apps in iTunes connect due to some reason, now want to delete them. These apps are never uploaded to app store.

Have already deselected all territories under rights and pricing. But why they still show "Prepare for Upload", and "Delete" button doesn't show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to delete app in iTunes Connect with "Developer Rejected" status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258255/unable-to-delete-app-in-itunes-connect-with-developer-rejected-status)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an app which is waiting for upload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114051/how-to-delete-an-app-which-is-waiting-for-upload)

Answer (score 1):

Apple says that you can delete an app from iTunes Connect only after it has one approved version. Check my answer here: [Unable to delete app in iTunes Connect with "Developer Rejected" status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258255/unable-to-delete-app-in-itunes-connect-with-developer-rejected-status/19575239#19575239)

Comment: The status is different in this case: the app is not in rejected state. However, Apple recently prevented removing versions that were rejected. Maybe this is a side-effect. I think they don't want people to check how their system works by creating many apps with small variations. This is just a guess.